# PHP Dynamic Nested Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an associative array which is generated dynamically with the values from database. When I print the whole array, it gives something like this when we put print_r($array).

```
  Array ( [95a5c80811239526fb75cbf31740cc35] => Array ( [product_id] => 2324) )
```

When I echo like this,

```
echo $array['95a5c80811239526fb75cbf31740cc35']['product_id'];
```

it gives me product id.
But the problem is, the code '95a5c80811239526fb75cbf31740cc35' changes dynamically everytime. I want to echo the product id irrespective of this code.

I tried

```
$array[]['product_id'];
$array['']['product_id'];
```

But not working. Can anyone help me? Please ask me if you have any doubts.

Comment: Is there always only a single element in the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`reset()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) in this case:

```
$array = array(
    '95a5c80811239526fb75cbf31740cc35' => array( // dynamic
        'product_id' => 2324
    ),
);

$value = reset($array); // set pointer to first element
echo $value['product_id']; // 2324
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the code is always the first element in the array:

```
$array[0]['product_id'];
```

If you collectively want all of the product ID's:

```
foreach($array as $product){
    $productIds[] = $product['product_id'];
}

// $productIds is now what $array was, but without the codes, so the product_id's are the first elements.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use for each for this so that you can get the value of product Id

```
 $array = Array ( [95a5c80811239526fb75cbf31740cc35] => Array ( [product_id] => 2324) )

foreach($array as $product){
echo $product['product_id'];
}
```

This would get your desired o/p

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation, there are few possible solutions:

```
$array = array_shift(array_values(
  Array(
    '95a5c80811239526fb75cbf31740cc35' =>
       Array(
          'product_id' => 2324
       )
    )));

echo $array['product_id']; // 2324
```

Another solution, probably more efficient:

```
echo array_shift(array_slice($array, 0, 1)); // 2324
```

For *PHP 5.4+* you could go with:

```
echo array_values($array)[0]; // 2324
```

Comment: This seems a long winded way to what is simply extracting the 2nd element of an array

Comment: What is so long in doing: `array_values($array)[0];` The other is just *study* examples.

Answer (score 1):

IF you are getting problem using Associative array then you can first convert it into numeric as follows

```
    $arr=array( 'first' => array( 'product_id' => 2324) );
    $arrr=array_values($arr);
     echo $arrr[0]['product_id'];
```

Output:

```
2324
```

Hope this helps and to know about array_values go [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
$array[0]['product_id'];
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: This will return a value, but it's not clear from the question if it will be the right one. It might be safer to use `array_shift` to get the first item without using an index at all.